# Getting unusual for loop output in C

Tags: c

I get an unusual output for the loop below. When it is run in my compiler, the output is `233445`. Why do I get this output for the loop below? `7` would be the only reasonable output for this loop, why don’t I get `7` when the `printf` statement is inside the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%d", i + j); 
}
```

Comment: "why don't I get 7 when the `printf` statement is inside the loop?" Because `i<4` and `j<3`, so `i+j < 4+3` and it means `i+j<7`, so `i+j` won't be `7` inside the loop.

Comment: i and j have a value of 1 before the loop

Answer (score 6):

> Why do I get this output for the loop below?

Make a chart and you will see.

```
i | j | i+j
--+---+----------------------------
1 | 1 | 2
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | (get out of the inner loop)
2 | 1 | 3
2 | 2 | 4
2 | 3 | (get out of the inner loop)
3 | 1 | 4
3 | 2 | 5
3 | 3 | (get out of the inner loop)
4 | - | (get out of the outer loop)
```

> why don't I get `7` when the `printf` statement is inside the loop?

Because `i<4` and `j<3`, so `i+j < 4+3` and it means `i+j<7`, so `i+j` won't be `7` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
int i ;
int j ;
for( i=1; i<4;i++)
     for(j=1;j<3;j++)
        printf("%d",i+j);     
}
```

The code runs an outer loop three times beginning with `i = 1`. It goes to the inner loop and runs twice beginning with `j = 1`. Then it prints `2,3` for the first loop, `3,4` for the second loop, and `4,5` for the third loop.

I added the commas for clarity and to show the inner loop does indeed run twice, but the actual output is `233445` because you're not adding any separators or newlines.

If you want `7` as the output using loops, try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int i ;
    int j ;
    for( i=4; i<5;i++) { // this brace means it contains the inner loop.
        for(j=3;j<4;j++) { // this inner brace means it contains control of the statement.
            printf("%d",i+j); // and always remember to indent for your readers
        } // close the inner brace!
    } // close the outer brace!
} // close main brace
```

Alternatively, you can try incrementing the numbers using loops, and then print it outside of the loops, as others have mentioned:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int i ;
    int j ;
    for( i=1; i<4;i++) { // this brace means it contains the inner loop.
        for(j=1;j<3;j++) { // this inner brace means it contains control of the statement.
        } // close the inner brace!
    } // close the outer brace!
    printf("%d",i+j); // 7
} // close main brace
```

Comment: Maybe adding the braces for the two loops will make things easier for the OP

Comment: @babon Good idea. I've appended this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `printf` statement is inside the loop. To get `7`, you take it out of the loop by placing `{}` after the loop.